# can not access mySql result in php

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have this mySQL query:

```
Select MIN(A.product_id  + 1)
From   Tabel A Left Join Tabel B
On A.product_id = B.product_id - 1
Where  B.product_id Is NULL
```

I run it on phpMyAdmin and this is the result:

[image: phpMyAdmin screenshot]

It returns the correct value (1803020005) but under the field 'MIN(a.product_id + 1)'.

How can I use it in php?

I use this but does not work:

```
$result = mysql_query ($select, $con);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

this is the result of $result = mysql_query ($select, $con); :

> Resource id #6

and this is the result of $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); :

> Array

Comment: Why don't you print_r your $row and see what it contains (and post it)? Also, you should be using MySQLi or PDO, as php_mysql is _deprecated_.

Comment: Great informative question with good documentation. +1

Comment: @David this is the result of $result = mysql_query ($select, $con); : 'Resource id #6' and this is the result of $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); : 'Array'

Comment: @David : I think aliasing to 'min' is doing something strange. please help

Comment: Unfortunately, I really don't have much experience with the php_mysql extension anymore, as I haven't used it in something like six years. was that 'Array' your entire result of print_r? The MySQL extension is doing something wacky or your query is invalid.

Comment: @David Yes that is all it prints on page on using echo. the $row['min'] is null!!! I think aliasing is doing something strange

Comment: echo your mysql_error(). but seriously, use PDO or MySQLi!!

Comment: there is no error. just 'min' is NULL

Answer (score 2):

You want to `SELECT MIN(a.product_id +1) AS min` and then get it under `$row['min'];`

Comment: it seems $row['min'] has nothing in it as echo does not show anything

Answer (score 1):

```
Select MIN(A.product_id  + 1) AS product_id
From   Tabel A Left Join Tabel B
On A.product_id = B.product_id - 1
Where  B.product_id Is NULL
```

try telling it what you want the field to be returned as

Answer (score 0):

Your query is completely wrong....

`On A.product_id = B.product_id -1 WHERE b.product_id IS NULL`

Is telling MySQL that A.product_id must be the same as b.product_id subtracted by 1 as long as b.product_id is empty

Now, I think that you're looking for `WHERE B.product_id IS NOT NULL` and all your woes will be repaired.

Also, read up on mysqli and PDO as the mysql extensions (ie: mysql_query) are not maintained and contain a lot of security issues..  PDO takes some getting used to, mysqli you can switch to relatively easy without much hassle..

Comment: Thanks @justin but I am seeing true answer in phpmyadmin! please take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265833/can-not-access-mysql-result-in-php)